# Can't connect to MySQL server thru command line but Workbench server is connected

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I'm able to connect to server `localhost:3306` with user `root` on `MySQL` Workbench using the GUI for `MySQL`, but I'm not able to connect to the **same** server when typing `mysql -u root -p` on my `Mac OS` terminal command line.

I remember the password I set when setting up a database, and I'm able to set up the server when using the GUI for `MySQL` in System Preferences on `Mac`. So why can't I connect  when doing `mysql -u root -p` using the same password? When I did it, it said the following:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost', using password: YES.
```

Thanks so much; I appreciate any swift answers!

Comment: You did define the password as such `mysql -u root -ppassword` , didn't you? Also note that there's no space between `-p` and the password value.

Comment: hey @FanoFN, I did define the password–however, I defined the password using the MySQL GUI on the Mac when I first installed MySQL; i didn't define it using Terminal. Would I have to redefine the password then to fix the issue? If so, how would I do that in Terminal?

Comment: Well, unless you're connection through terminal with a pre-defined setting (usually an external file) then yes, you must define the password. Currently, you're trying to connect with this line of code `mysql -u root -p`, right? Now try with `mysql -u root -pyourpassword`.. and as I said before, there should be no space between the `-p` and your password value.